# Firebase for Push Notifications only

Tags: django, firebase, grails, web-applications, push-notification

I want to develop a web application with a database using Django/Grails/Express

I want to use Firebase just for sending Push Notifications to an Iphone. Do i need develop the webapplication (including the database) in firebase or can i develop the web application using Django/Grails/Express and use Firebase just for sending Push Notifications?

Do all web frameworks (Django/Grails/Express) support Firebase? Will Firebase be free to use in my case?

EDIT: How to i use Firebase with Django/Grails/Express? Is there an API or library i need to download?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can pick and choose which Firebase products you wish to use in your app.  You may use as many or as few as you want.  There is no obligation to use anything that you don't want to use.  There is no charge for using Firebase Cloud Messaging in your app.

Comment: Thank you! And also i dont need to develop the iOS application with Firebase right? I can just develop it normally with Xcode?

Comment: Firebase isn't an IDE like Xcode.  Firebase comes as a set of SDKs and a console.

Comment: Oh... i thought i read somewhere that you can also develop an iOS App using Firebase.

Comment: You can develop apps "with" lots of different things that have nothing to do with each other.  Don't get confused by the terminology.  Study the products to understand what they do.

Answer (score -1):

In this url https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/grails3-send-push-notification-using-firebase-cloud-messaging you can read about the process for sending push notifications using grails as backend

Comment: Thanks! Is there also one for Django/Express? I fluctuate between these three frameworks.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.